# How to print name of file on one line in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

I have this short PHP code

```
<?php
$directory = "Documents";
$a = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

foreach($a as $key => $name){
    $link = "some http to director" . $name;
    echo  "<a href='$link' >$name</a><br>";
}
?>
```

but this code gives me every character on separate line.

Comment: Use PHP native class for Directory iteration. http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php

Comment: your code is running fine for me:- Check this:- http://prntscr.com/9u3zk0(screenshot of my document folder) and http://prntscr.com/9u3zqr (output of the php code)

Comment: Same here, I ran it locally and everything works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by *every character on separate line*? Are you referring to the output generated by `echo`? If so: How about removing the `<br>` from that statement?

Comment: "Same here, I ran it locally and everything works as expected"? so where is the problem?

Comment: I am working with Adobe Muse. When I insert this PHP code directly into file -  this is  the result: http://postimg.org/image/vctof72cj/
When I insert PHP code with Adobe Muse - this is result: http://postimg.org/image/innmi2z87/

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is putting your link on a new line, substitute it with a space or other separator.

Comment: in <br> is not mistake :/

Comment: so i don't understand what you want to obtain, could you please add a couple of examples of expected results?

Comment: Now I have this output http://postimg.org/image/w1yb85ur3/. There is not one name of docx on the one line. Can you help?